# google-translate-api giving an error in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

while importing **google-translate-api** on my React Native app, I'm getting an error *"couldn't resolve the module querystring"*.

Please find the attached screenshot.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqacZ.png)

**Error:**
*Unable to resolve module "querystring" from "...". Module "querystring" does not exist in the Haste module map.*

Comment: FYP. Please, always use text format instead of screenshots when posting an error message.

Comment: please provide the npm link `google-translate-api`